# Is there any way to concurrently decrypt a big encrypted file with RSA in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have 24 quite big RSA-encrypted files and I want to decrypt them. I'm using Threads to decrypt them independently, but I still takes too much time to get a result. So the question is whether I can use multiple threads inside decrypting one file.

Comment: People downvoting this; the OP is asking if the approach is even feasible and not the complete solution.  We can at least from our experience help the OP with that.

Comment: Maybe this fits better at https://codereview.stackexchange.com, though I recommend that you read their [help center page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) first to see what is on-topic over there

Comment: try using lambda function or asynchronous programming

Comment: Unless you've got more than 24 CPU cores, throwing more threads at a task is unlikely to bring any further improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, isn't RSA a handshake? You probably mean AES.

Second, make sure you have all the buffered i/o stream with 8192 or 16384 or more bytes, just a precaution.

Third, I don't think it is trivial because the crypto is by design a stream or block algo for which subsequent bytes depends on ealier ones.

That being said, if you were extremely competent in crypto and willing to redo it all by hand, you could pipeline various steps of the decryption over few threads (perhaps using a simple queue&threads seda or ring&threads disruptor pattern).

Decrypting AES file (or the opposite) likely requires a few embarassingly sequential steps (to borrow from the expression "embarassingly parallel") like file's bytes loading, block hash verification, cipher update and decryption.

If you stick with multiple threads independently processing files, you are probably using well your CPU but contending on disk. And if you reduce threads to minimize disk contention, you under-exploit CPU. So it is important to look into both disk and cpu usage to target the correct bottleneck and decouple the thread count for i/o from the thread count for cpu. Isolating your block of bytes decryption from disk loading could be a good first step.